# Swift - deinit not called

Tags: memory, swift4

Hmm...

I'm having a little problem with an unexpected behaviour in Swif4 memory management. In fact I'm missing a deinit call

Basically the layout of the code part failing is like this:

```
class A {
    init() {
        print("A init \(unsafeBitCast(self, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)) called")
    }

    deinit {
        print("A deinit \(unsafeBitCast(self, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)) called")
    }

    func c() {
        print("A c called")
    }
}


class B {
    var a : A

    init() {

        a = A()   <-- required because a is not optional

    }

    func c() {
        a = A()
        a.c()
    }
}

var b = B()
b.c()
b.c()
b.c()
```

I simulated this in playground and the (expected) printout was this (w/o comments):

```
A init 0x000060c00000c540 called     <-- initial init
A init 0x000060c00000c800 called     <-- first b.c()
A deinit 0x000060c00000c540 called
A c called
A init 0x000060400000c4c0 called     <-- second b.c()
A deinit 0x000060c00000c800 called   
A c called
A init 0x000060400000c4a0 called     <-- third b.c()
A deinit 0x000060400000c4c0 called   
A c called
```

Unfortunately my real life classes don't behave like so. In fact they act like so:

```
A init 0x000060c00000c540 called     <-- initial init
A init 0x000060c00000c800 called     <-- first b.c()
A deinit 0x000060c00000c540 called
A c called
A init 0x000060400000c4c0 called     <-- second b.c()
A deinit 0x000060c00000c800 called   <-- missing!
A c called
A init 0x000060400000c4a0 called     <-- third b.c()
A deinit 0x000060400000c4c0 called   <-- missing!
A c called
```

So, basically only the first deinit appears, no subsequents. I fear memory leaks (although Instruments doesn't give me a hint).

Any idea, what operations could provoke this behaviour? I don't have circular references, at least I don't see them.

Comment: Could be a reference to B somewhere... B is supporting URLSessionDelegate protocol.... EDIT: It _is_ most likely caused by that. If I remove URLSessionDelegate support, everything is fine.

Comment: Playground or REPL (including LLDB console) is not a good place to check ARC-related behaviors. Create a Command Line Tool or any other actual app project to test your code.

Comment: Right. I was just using playground in order to demonstrate (myself) the proper expected behaviour. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

OK, fixed. The problem was, that my "A" class was held as reference by a URLSession (as delegate). Because this session was not terminated properly, the A object was not deinitialized.